# ¿Existe forma de cifrar mensajes con llave pública, y descifrar mensajes recibidos en un cliente web?

Tags: web, seguridad, cifrado

La consulta esta.
Supongo que tiene una respuesta sencilla, pero desconozco el camino a seguir.
Teniendo un cliente en Android genero un par de llaves (privada/pública), comparto la llave pública con el otro cliente (Android por ejemplo), quien a su vez cifra los mensajes utilizando esta última. Básicamente el cifrado punto a punto.
Mi duda es si el cliente utiliza un browser (Chrome, Firefox, lo que sea etc....).
¿Es posible que el cliente web genere un par de llaves (ajeno a la interacción del usuario) y utilice el mismo esquema para cifrar/descifrar los mensajes?
Tengo la duda de cómo Whatsapp y aplicaciones similares de mensajería realizan el cifrado punto a punto desde el navegador.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: No es cifrado punto a punto, tenes cifrado Simetrico y Asimetrico. Llave Publica/Privada es asimetrico y Simetrico, usan los dos la misma llave privada. Depende de que necesitas es lo que debes usar, en que lenguaje estas trabajando? Aunque no trabajes con .Net te dejo el link con la documentacion de microsoft de como funciona en la teoria y te muestra como lo aplicas en sus Librerias. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-model

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, entiendo que no es cifrado punto a punto, gracias por la aclaración. Recién empiezo a leer y tengo algunas dudas.
Estoy trabajando en NodeJs con un front en VueJs. Está bastante avanzado, y si bien todo el proyecto corre por https, quisiera añadir una capa de seguridad para los usuarios ya que los mensajes entre los usuarios no se guardarán en el servidor, y tampoco quiero un man in the middle.

Comment: ahi tenes informacion con explicacion de los casos a mi parecer muy bien explicado, para que luego lo apliques en java con sus librerias.